# Autodesk Model Derivative API: Revit to IFC translation with exportSettingsName option does not create PSET in 2023 files

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-model-derivative

I am translating revit files (.rvt) to IFC (.ifc) files using the [model derivative API](https://aps.autodesk.com/en/docs/model-derivative/v2/reference/http/jobs/job-POST/). I am setting attributes as described in the section "Attributes that Apply to IFC Outputs" in the documentation, namely exportSettingName (formats.advanced.exportSettingName). Here, I pass the name of the IFC export setting as stored in the Revit file to translate.

This export setting has the "Export schedules as property sets" set to true, also its sub-option "Export only schedules containing IFC, Pset, or Common in the title" set to true.

The Revit file also contains a schedule (named starting with IFC_).

When using the API to translate a Revit File of the **version 2021**, the API yields the expected result, ie. an IFC file with a custom PSET named like the schedule and containing all the properties described in the schedule.

However, after migrating this file to **2023**, the API does not yield the expected result anymore, ie. creates an IFC file without this PSET.

Was there a change in the API or in the way the export settings need to be stored in the revit file?

Comment: I'm sorry to hear this issue is bothering you, but it's hard to tell why MD API doesn't export the schedule as IFC Pset without looking into your model settings. You might know that MD API doesn't support custom IFC export settings set created by the recent Revit IFC Addin. (RVTLMV-3166). See limitations in [this blog post](https://aps.autodesk.com/blog/export-ifc-rvt-using-model-derivative-api). Probably, your IFC export settings are upgraded to the new one while upgrading from Revit 2021 to 2023. Could you share a test RVT file encountering this issue to `aps(DOT)help(AT)autodesk(DOT)com`?

Comment: No need to share the whole model. Remaining a couple of elements and IFC export settings inside are enough.

Comment: @EasonKang, is there still no bugfix out for RVTLMV-3166? We are constantly shifting new projects towards Revit 2023 and need IFC settings in every IFC export

Comment: Sorry, our engineering team encountered some technical difficulties and is still finding solutions right now, as far as I know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out (thank you Eason for the comprehensive response and information via email) that **there is no way** to pass custom export settings **in Revit 2023** files.

To be more precise, the Model Derivative API does not (yet) support the format that Revit 2023 (the 2023 IFC Addin) writes the settings into the model. A revit file that was migrated from Revit 2021 to Revit 2023 can have Model Derivative API compatible custom IFC settings until the settings are changed (which was the problem in our case).

For more details follow the [blog post](https://aps.autodesk.com/blog/export-ifc-rvt-using-model-derivative-api) in Eason Kangs first comment to the question.